# Why does transitioning the transform scale of an element cause some children elements to jitter

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to scale a card element when a user hovers over it by using only the transform of the card.

However I'm noticing that in a lot of cases when the card is hovered, the child elements will jitter in some way, i.e. some letters jumping up in height for a split second.

Here's an example of the effect that i keep experiencing.

[image: hover effect]

https://codepen.io/andrewmumblebee/pen/OrBGzm

You'll notice that the S of TEST, jumps in height during the transition.

I've managed to get a completely smooth transition working before, but this was absolutely positioned.

https://codepen.io/andrewmumblebee/pen/REevdB

After removing the absolute positioning, etc. it still is smooth, so I'm assuming it's something to do with having multiple child elements.

Here's the important code, the full code can be found on the first Codepen link.

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Godot_icon.svg" />
            <div class="text">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
    body {
        background: #478cbf;
    }

    .container {
        margin: 50px auto;
        width: 200px;
    }

    img {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .card {
        width: 250px;
        height: 300px;
        background: linear-gradient(#444, #333);
        transition: all 0.3s;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 30px;
        will-change: transform;
        transform: scale(1);
        box-shadow: rgba(#000000, 0.2) 5px 5px 10px;
    }

    .text {
        font-size: 50px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: white;
        font-family: arial;
        will-change: transform;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .card:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
        box-shadow: rgba(#000000, 0.2) 10px 10px 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Because font rendering generally sucks. Too many variables – fonts, libs,  browser, os, gpu driver, … All four letters jitter in my Firefox for example.

Comment: I'd try changing the font-size of the text. Some sizes are worse, some are better. Chrome 71 has no noticeable jitter with a font-size of 46px.

Comment: I _suspect_ this is because sub-pixel antialiasing is only applied in the 'stable' end and start states, and not during transition. Try experimenting with the `-webkit-font-smoothing` & `font-smooth` CSS properties

Comment: Although I have to say in Safari (12.0.2) there is no jitter, with your unmodified codepen, whereas in Chrome there is for every letter, so I'm almost inclined to say: **Chrome bug**